# Using Deblector with .NET Reflector 7

Tags: .net, debugging, reflector

I'm trying to use the Deblector addin with Reflector 7.1.0.143. I tried other pre-existing addins, and none of them worked until I discovered this post:

http://forums.reflector.net/questions/217/baml-add-in

where it talks about targetting .NET 3.5 and 'Any CPU'.  I did this for other addins (e.g. BamlViewer) and I'm now able to use it with this latest version of Reflector.  I tried the same thing with Deblector (which I got from http://deblector.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) but I get the generic addin failed to load message.

I attached to the Reflector.exe process and set breakpoints in the 'EntryPoint' class' constructor and the IPackage.Load() method, but neither breakpoints are hit (although debug symbols are successfully loaded and breakpoints appear active).

Has anyone got Deblector to work with the latest version of Reflector?  Any debugging/diagnostic tips for analyzing Reflector add in load failures?

Thanks,
Notre

Answer (score 0):

Ah, hello again.

I've answered this elsewhere, http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=13596, however the answer is spread over several posts so, just to summarise:

1. Reflector 5.x and 6.x add-ins can be loaded unmodified in Reflector 7 as of build 7.2.0.134, which I put out as an early access build today. You can get this from the bottom of the homepage at http://www.reflector.net/. I anticipate that we'll release .NET Reflector 7.2 for real within the next 10 days or so.
2. You can find out why an add-in failed to load by double-clicking on the add-in name in the error box that appears - this is well hidden and is something we'll make more obvious in the future.